# any idea about x-y component and xy-axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

My problem when i take snapshot from the camera connected to my laptop, the y-axis become inverting so the result become wrong "http://s4.postimg.org/xcat1kmvh/sdsf.png"... i fix this problem by use this code " set(gca,'YDir','normal') %starts at the bottom of the figure
 "...but the problem is that the photo become inverting like this " http://s16.postimg.org/ekguxl35x/sdsfss.png "... how i can fix this problem ... i just want to get XY component of any joints in the pic ...

this is my code : i just take snapshot for calibration before i record a video

imagesc(getsnapshot(handles.video));

set(gca,'YDir','normal') %starts at the bottom of the figure

```
[x1,y1]=ginput(1)
[x2,y2]=ginput(1)
c=sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)

 d=c/40.8;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invert the image before you plot it so that when you reverse the y axis, the image ends up in the orientation you want.  Here's an example

```
I = imread('peppers.png'); % sample image included in matlab
subplot(2,2,1)
imagesc(I)
subplot(2,2,2)
I2 = flipdim(I,1);
imagesc(I2)
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
```

[image]

In your code, `getsnapshot(handles.video))`returns a matrix and you can invert that matrix.  Something like this:

```
frame = getsnapshot(handles.video));
frame2 = flipdim(frame,1);
imagesc(frame2)
```

Comment: i can't do your idea because i don't save the picture that i took...i just take snapshot do identify 2 points on the wood that's appear in the link i put "http://s4.postimg.org/xcat1kmvh/sdsf.png". ... then i will have a scaling factor to convert from pixel to cm ... then i record a video and convert it to frames and finally i do digitizing on each frames ...

Comment: You don't need to save the picture, just store it in a variable before you display it. I updated my answer.

Comment: give me this error >>>


Error: File: MAFSA.m Line: 346 Column: 35
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
 
>> MAFSA
Error using flipdim (line 21)
Requires two arguments.

Error in MAFSA>snapshot_Callback (line 347)
frame2 = flipdim(frame);

Comment: typo. Try: frame2 = flipdim(frame,1);

Comment: it is working ... I want to thank you for your help me ... thank you very much ... but this done for the snapshot ...how i can do it for frames ... this is my code for digitizing ...


 readerobj= VideoReader(get(handles.recall_the_video,'string'));
    vidFrames = read(readerobj);
    numFrames = get(readerobj, 'numberOfFrames');
    
    N = str2double(get(handles.points,'string'));
    

    
   x=[];
   y=[];
   n=1;
    
 for k = 1:numFrames
    mov(k).cdata = vidFrames(:,:,:,k);
     imshow(mov(k).cdata);
 for j=1:N
     [a,b]=ginput(1);
     x(n)=a;  
     y(n)=b;
   n=n+1;
   end
 end

Comment: Hard to see what going on there, but I think you can assign mov(k).cdata to a variable and then use flipdim to invert it before you display it. Consider accepting the answers if they work for you!

Comment: hey, guys, have you checked `axis xy` and `axis ij` commands?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can cheat using :

```
set(gca, 'YTicklabel', {'450' '400' '350' '300' '250' '200' '150' '100' '50'})
```

Comment: @roger1 you can play with the number of elements in the cell array.